# Create sequence of values based on multiple column values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.frame that is a result of a near neighbor search of points, and it has three columns: V1 represents the index of closest point, V2 the second closest point, and V3 the third:

```
search_result <- structure(list(V1 = c(1350L, 1390L, 1411L, 1437L, 1444L, 1895L, 
                                       1895L, 1467L, 1478L, 1500L), 
                                V2 = c(1351L, 1391L, 1410L, 1438L, 
                                       1907L, 1456L, 1456L, 1466L, 1477L, 1499L), 
                                V3 = c(1349L, 1389L, 1940L, 1913L, 1445L, 1894L, 
                                       1894L, 1884L, 1479L, 1501L)), 
                           row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
                           class = "data.frame")
```

As I want the closest neighbor point, I would select V1 as the result and I would be fine. It happens that I also want the index to be ordered, and V1 has some index that are out of order. So **I want to** create a column that will give me the value of V1  (when it's in order) or the value of V2 or V3 (and V2 has the priority) so the order is preserved. In this case the result would be like:

```
     V1   V2   V3 ordered
1  1350 1351 1349    1350
2  1390 1391 1389    1390
3  1411 1410 1940    1411
4  1437 1438 1913    1437
5  1444 1907 1445    1444
6  1895 1456 1894    1456 #take V2 instead
7  1895 1456 1894    1456 #take V2 instead
8  1467 1466 1884    1467
9  1478 1477 1479    1478
10 1500 1499 1501    1500
```

I tried to take the minimum value of each column, but there are cases later on the dataset which the max value would be the desired (not the best option, but closer to the expected). In the example below, there is discontinuity on rows 2, 4, 5 and 6, so I would take the value of V2 (priority) or V3 as the desired, so the "order" is maintained:

```
# it's harder to see the "order" here, but it starts in V1 = 1881

   V1   V2   V3  ordered
1 1881 1470 1880    1881
2 1457 1893 1894    1893 #take V2 instead
3 1907 1444 1906    1907
4 1442 1443 1908    1908 #take V3 instead
5 1433 1918 1432    1918 #take V2 instead
6 1402 1949 1401    1949 #take V2 instead
7 1968 1969 1967    1968
8 1985 1986 1984    1985
9 1992 1993 1991    1992
```

The full dataset has 2500 points, and the "unordered" values happen in roughly 10% of it, so I can estimate what's the "order".

Any `base` `tidyverse` or `data.table` help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would it suffice to take the minimum of the columns? That seems to fit for your example data but I don't know if that will work more generally. If not, is there a consistent mathematical way to identify which rows are "out of order"?

Comment: I added some cases where the minimum would not suffice. I can identify (using ``diff``) where probably there is a discontinuity, but it would also identify some "ok" values as suspicious, specially when there is a transition from a bad to an ok value.

Comment: It seems like there could be multiple possible solutions in some cases, e.g. couldn't V2 values be used in row 8+9 and still be "in order"? What if you could fix a V1 out-of-order with V2 in one row and V3 in another, or alternately V3 and V2 -- which match is better?

Comment: V2 is always a better match than V3. So If V1 is "out of order" and V2 e V3 are "in order", I'll always take V2.

Comment: Why row 3 returns `V1` (1411) when the row is not ordered? Also can you update the post with expected output of second dataframe?

Comment: What happens if at some point none of `V1:V3` are greater or equal to the `ordered` value from the previous row?

Comment: @RonakShah it's the column V1 that's supposed to be ordered. In this case, it's in order because it grows from 1350, 1390, ``1411``, 1437

Comment: @Alexis in this case I assume the ordered value would be NA. Actually, I can ask the neighbour search algorithm for as many ``Vn`` as I want. Here I asked for 3 because I just guessed that if V1 wouldn't give the ordered value, V2 would, and if V2 wouldn't, V3 would.

Comment: In the first example, row 6, why would you take `V2` if `1895 > 1444` (i.e., order is still increasing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `V1` should always be increasing, we can take first value of `V1` as reference and subtract all the values from 2nd row by this `first_value` and take the one which gives the minimum difference. Since, we also want to consider priority one way is to multiply the difference by incremental number. In this example, I have just multiplied it by integers 1, 2 and 3. So the first difference is multiplied by 1, second by 2 and so on. More complex methods can be thought of to assign priority if some edge case are found.

```
first_value <- search_result$V1[1]
search_result$ordered <- c(first_value, apply(search_result[-1, ], 1, function(x) {
     x <- x[x > first_value]
     x[which.min((x - first_value) * seq_along(x))]
}))

search_result
#     V1   V2   V3 ordered
#1  1350 1351 1349    1350
#2  1390 1391 1389    1390
#3  1411 1410 1940    1411
#4  1437 1438 1913    1437
#5  1444 1907 1445    1444
#6  1895 1456 1894    1456
#7  1895 1456 1894    1456
#8  1467 1466 1884    1467
#9  1478 1477 1479    1478
#10 1500 1499 1501    1500
```

This also works for the second dataset, consider it as `df`

```
first_value <- df$V1[1]
df$ordered <- c(first_value, apply(df[-1, ], 1, function(x) {
     x <- x[x > first_value]
     x[which.min((x - first_value) * seq_along(x))]
}))

df
#    V1   V2   V3 ordered
#1 1881 1470 1880    1881
#2 1457 1893 1894    1893
#3 1907 1444 1906    1907
#4 1442 1443 1908    1908
#5 1433 1918 1432    1918
#6 1402 1949 1401    1949
#7 1968 1969 1967    1968
#8 1985 1986 1984    1985
#9 1992 1993 1991    1992
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do is iterate over each column returned by the search and first each row, keeping the first value that satisfies the indices being in order.

Start with assuming the first column is in order. Move to the second column and replace any rows where this is not true. Move to the third column, comparing to your updated ordered column. Continue for all the columns.

There may be a more optimized way of coding this (such as checking if the answer converges prior to iterating all of the columns) but here is a compact way to achieve this (note the `lag` function is `dplyr::lag` not `stats::lag`) :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# using the second data set
# assuming at least one column will satisfy the constraints
data.frame(
  V1 = c(1881, 1457, 1907, 1442, 1433, 1402, 1968, 1985, 1992),
  V2 = c(1470, 1893, 1444, 1443, 1918, 1949, 1969, 1986, 1993),
  V3 = c(1880, 1894, 1906, 1908, 1432, 1401, 1967, 1984, 1991)
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    ordered = reduce(., ~ifelse(.x >= lag(.x, default = 0), .x, .y))
  )

#>     V1   V2   V3 ordered
#> 1 1881 1470 1880    1881
#> 2 1457 1893 1894    1893
#> 3 1907 1444 1906    1907
#> 4 1442 1443 1908    1908
#> 5 1433 1918 1432    1918
#> 6 1402 1949 1401    1949
#> 7 1968 1969 1967    1968
#> 8 1985 1986 1984    1985
#> 9 1992 1993 1991    1992
```

If you're not sure if you've returned enough columns from the nearest neighbor search, you'll have to add one more iteration to check if the ordered column is ascending

```r
search_results <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(1881, 1457, 1907, 1442, 1433, 1402, 1968, 1785, 1992),
  V2 = c(1470, 1893, 1444, 1443, 1918, 1949, 1969, 1786, 1993),
  V3 = c(1880, 1894, 1906, 1908, 1432, 1401, 1967, 1784, 1991)
) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    ordered = reduce(., ~ifelse(.x >= lag(.x, default = 0), .x, .y))
  )

with(search_results, any(ordered < lag(ordered, default = 0)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the ``reduce``! It doesn't work in the first example though.

Comment: First, in rows 5-6 there is clearly a "discontinuity", but it's still ordered. So I thought I could set a threshold (lets say 100) to determine if there was a discontinuity or not: ``ordered = reduce(., ~ifelse(abs(.x - lag(.x, default = 0)) <= 100, .x, .y)``. It works in this situation, but it also label the transition from rows 7-8 as a discontinuity (and doesn't label row 7 as unordered, as it is the case)

Comment: Can you clarify your logic on selecting the value for the ordered column? 

From your comment above is it 1) the values have to be in ascending order 2) and the first value that is not a discontinuity (as determined by a threshold)? 

The second point meaning that the selected value doesn't have to be the absolute closest to the previous value, just within a threshold. I.e. this is why for the second data set, row three 1907 is selected instead of 1906 (even though the latter is closer to 1893)